# How to create an applet project in maven?

Tags: maven-2, applet

What is the best way how to create an applet project in maven?
Is there any archetype that I missed? Or I just need to create regular java project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a normal Java project. You may find the proguard-maven-plugin useful, in order to compress the applet .jar.

Comment: Thank you for answer and suggesting proguard-maven-plugin.